# Why is my data plotting with flat lines instead of a regular line chart? R

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is my Data

```
print(mydata)

Quarter    Freq
2016 Q2     89
2016 Q3    1401
2016 Q4    1303
2017 Q1    1205
2017 Q2    1620
2017 Q3    2019
2017 Q4    1632
2018 Q1    1664
2018 Q2    1755
2018 Q3    1708
2018 Q4    1408
2019 Q1    1533
2019 Q2    2075
2019 Q3    2262
2019 Q4    1408
```

When I try to create a line plot, I get a weird plot I've never seen before. 
I ran str(mydata)

$ Quarter is a Factor

$ Freq is an int

```
 plot(mydata$Quarter, mydata$Freq, type = "l")
```

[image]

Here is the dput()

```
structure(list(Quarter = structure(1:15, .Label = c("2016 Q2", 
"2016 Q3", "2016 Q4", "2017 Q1", "2017 Q2", "2017 Q3", "2017 Q4", 
"2018 Q1", "2018 Q2", "2018 Q3", "2018 Q4", "2019 Q1", "2019 Q2", 
"2019 Q3", "2019 Q4"), class = "factor"), Freq = c(89, 1401, 
1303, 1205, 1620, 2019, 1632, 1664, 1755, 1708, 1408, 1533, 2075, 
2262, 1408)), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = "data.frame")
```

This looks like a bar chart with no fill. But I want a line chart.

What am I doing wrong? I want to to this is base R graphics but I cant get the output I want in ggplot either
thank you.

Comment: It looks like an digit "1" you placed there, instead of "l" for line.

Comment: Hello, I have "l" in my code and still nothing. I updated the post.

Comment: Since the amount of data is not so big, could you provide it with dput()? So we can try to see what's happening.

Comment: @user2332849 I included the dput().

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your x-axis data "Quarter" is discontinuous: it's being read in as a character factor with 15 levels.  In order to draw the line, `ggplot` and `plot` need to know they they are connected (continuous data).  Confirm this yourself with `str(mydata)`.

You need to convert `mydata$Quarter` into something that `ggplot` and `plot` can read as continuous data, then you should get a line.  I don't use base graphics, so here's what I have in a simple way using `ggplot2`.  You will need to use the `as.yearqtr()` function from the `zoo` library.

```
library(zoo)
mydata$Quarter <- as.yearqtr(mydata$Quarter)
```

Now `mydata$Quater` is a data type called "yearqtr".  Here's my example of your plot, although you may want to fix it up a bit however you want:

```
ggplot(mydata, aes(Quarter, Freq)) + geom_line()
```

[image]

You may have to adjust or convert that `mydata$Quarter` to another format as you need to.  Working with dates has a lot going on... I would suggest checking out the `lubridate` library for a lot of useful information.  [This is also a decent reference](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~s133/dates.html).